# Use socket.io v1.3.x to send request from a single user to a set of predefined users

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Here is what I want to achieve with the latest version of Socket.io i.e. 1.3.7

A logged in member user can broadcast same information to a set of predefined admin users. And a single admin user can receive responses from a particular set of member users. All in real-time.

For example, a user from New York only want to send real-time request to those admins who are also from New York. And on the Admin Panel, an admin from New York will only receive request from the users of New York. And that user is unaware of an another user from New York connected to the same room.

Socket.io +1.0 provides the functionally of namespacing and creating rooms, and I was thinking that the mentioned functionality can be achieved by creating rooms. But I was having problem of wrapping the concept of utilizing rooms for such a requirement around my head.

What I have guessed by far that, a room is needed to be created dynamically by the name of the locality, i.e. New York;

```
var room = 'new york' // string coming from client
socket.join(room);
```

And both the New York users and admin will connect to the room. But, the thing is that Admin can only see the request of users, not other admins, same as the users cannot view the request of other users from new york.

Is this system achievable using rooms, or is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different solution:
When user connect there is something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ ...
```

Before that code create array variable to store all sockets with additional data:

```
var connectionList = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var connection = {
    socket:socket,
    city: userCity,
    role: userRole
    ...
  }
  connectionList.push(connection);
}
```

And now when you want send message you itereate through all sockets and emit to only those that meet certain conditions, for example when user send request:

```
socket.on('somerequest', function(data){
  if(<some validation rules for data>){
    connectionList.forEach(function(otherConnection){
      if(<some conditions to send message>){
        otherConnection.socket.emit('message', somedata);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This gives you enormous possibilities of configuration.

But remember to remove from list closed connections!
Something like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  var i = connectionList.indexOf(connection);
  delete connectionList[i];
  connection = null;
});
```